# Как увеличить размер ячейки в dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: БД на access]Не могу никак разобраться, как увеличить размер ячейки в dataGridView, чтобы ячейка подстраивалась под размер текста.
Я хочу чтобы текст из ячейки "исследования" выводился в c# как же как и в acces. Но у меня он выводиться вот так.
[image: Вот как она выводиться в dataGridView]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: `dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;`

Comment: Спасибо, все роботает, но только при нажатии на ячейку, а как сделать чтобы при запуске программы она уже была развёрнута?

Comment: Все работе, я просто не туда вписал код, спасибо большое за помощь